# How to set up Firebase actionCodeSettings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to set up email user verification with Firebase and according to their documentation actionCodeSettings must be configured.

This is my code so far:

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'www.myDomain.com',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};
```

However, I get this error:
`error: {code: 400, message: "INVALID_CONTINUE_URI : Missing domain in continue url"`

I have also tried putting `handleCodeInApp` to false (as shown in this solution: [Firebase Passing State(continue to website link) in Password Reset Email and email verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211693/firebase-passing-statecontinue-to-website-link-in-password-reset-email-and-ema)), but I get no response in the console.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the protocol for the URL, eg.
url: 'https://www.example.com'